# Error initializing a docker container after installing transmission-daemon and nordvpn

Tags: docker, containers

1 - Created an image with the Dockerfile below (successfully)

```
docker build -t meu-container .
```

2 - Created a container from the created image

```
docker create -it --name meu-container meu-container /bin/bash
```

3 - I tried to run the created container but the following error message was displayed:

```
docker start -ia meu-container
```

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
```

**4 - How can I fix this error? Any sugestions?**

DOCKERFILE:

```
# Use a imagem base Ubuntu:latest
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Atualize e faça upgrade no apt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Instale os pacotes transmission-daemon e wget
RUN apt-get install -y transmission-daemon wget

# Baixe o script de instalação do NordVPN
RUN wget -qO nordvpn-install.sh https://downloads.nordcdn.com/apps/linux/install.sh

# Dê permissão de execução ao script
RUN chmod +x nordvpn-install.sh

# Execute o script de instalação do NordVPN
RUN sh -c 'yes | ./nordvpn-install.sh'

# Exponha a porta 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Execute o transmission-daemon
CMD ["/bin/sh", "transmission-daemon", "-f"]
```

I was hoping that the container would initialize successfully and I could use the bash prompt

Comment: That looks like your host shell (Windows Git Bash?) is rewriting the command line in a way that doesn't work with Docker.  That's not a problem with your Dockerfile.

Comment: (Consider just `docker run` your container, rather than separately `create` and `start`ing it.  You shouldn't need the `/bin/bash` override normally.  The Dockerfile `CMD` does _not_ need `/bin/sh` at the end – it will cause problems if `transmission-daemon` is anything other than a shell script.  Conversely, two lines above, `RUN` commands are automatically wrapped in `sh -c` and you do not need to `RUN sh -c ...`.)

Comment: Thanks David! The problem was really my Windows Git Bash. The container worked perfectly via cmd. Also, I fixed my DOCKERFILE with your suggestions and everything is working perfectly as it should. Thank you very much!